# Jeta: How to create custom annotation processors

Tags: java, android, annotation-processing, jeta, androjeta

There is [plenty of features](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide.html) that already available on `Jeta`, but what if something is missing. Can I create my own annotations and generate metacode for them?

Needed a step-by-step tutorial how to create custom `Jeta` processors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### How to create custom processors, step-by-step tutorial

#### Step 1: `Hello, World` project

For this tutorial let's create a simple `Gradle` project with one module `app` and with a single class `SayHelloApp`. This class writes `Hello, World!` to standard output.

[image: SayHelloApp]

For the illustration we are going to create `Hello` annotation that sets `Hello, Jeta!` string to the annotated fields.

#### Step 2: `common` module

First, we need a module that will be accessible in `app` and  `apt` (will create shortly) modules. In `common` module we need two classes - `Hello` annotation and `HelloMetacode` interface:

[image: common module]

#### Step 3: `apt` module

`apt` - is a module in which we'll create all the required for code generation classes. For this tutorial we need a processor that will handle our `Hello` annotation.

[image: apt module]

Note that this module depends on `common` module so we used `Hello` annotation as a parameter for the super constructor. By doing that we're saying to `Jeta` that we need all the elements annotated with given type. The module also depends on `jeta-apt` in order to get access to the `Jeta` classes.

#### Step 4: Processor

Created `SayHelloProcessor` now does nothing. Let's add some logic in it. The idea here is to generate java code that sets `Hello, Jeta` string to the fields annotated with `Hello`.

Note that `Jeta` uses `JavaPoet` to create java source code. It's really great framework by `Square`.  Please, check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/square/javapoet).

First, we need that our [metacode](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide/at-runtime.html) implements `HelloMetacode`. To do that we'll add super interface to the `builder`:

```
MetacodeContext context = roundContext.metacodeContext();
ClassName masterClassName = ClassName.get(context.masterElement());
builder.addSuperinterface(ParameterizedTypeName.get(
      ClassName.get(HelloMetacode.class), masterClassName));
```

Next, implement `HelloMetacode` by creating `void setHello(M master)` method:

```
MethodSpec.Builder methodBuilder = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("setHello")
    .addAnnotation(Override.class)
    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
    .returns(void.class)
    .addParameter(masterClassName, "master");
```

Finally, the statements for each element annotated with `Hello`, that `Jeta` passes in `process` method via `roundContext` parameter:

```
for (Element element : roundContext.elements()) {
    String fieldName = element.getSimpleName().toString();
    methodBuilder.addStatement("master.$L = \"Hello, Jeta\"", fieldName);
}
```

Here is the complete `SayHelloProcessor` listing:

```
package org.brooth.jeta.samples.apt;

import com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName;
import com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec;
import com.squareup.javapoet.ParameterizedTypeName;
import com.squareup.javapoet.TypeSpec;
import org.brooth.jeta.apt.MetacodeContext;
import org.brooth.jeta.apt.RoundContext;
import org.brooth.jeta.apt.processors.AbstractProcessor;

import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;

public class SayHelloProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    public SayHelloProcessor() {
      super(Hello.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(TypeSpec.Builder builder, RoundContext roundContext) {
      MetacodeContext context = roundContext.metacodeContext();
      ClassName masterClassName = ClassName.get(context.masterElement());
      builder.addSuperinterface(ParameterizedTypeName.get(
            ClassName.get(HelloMetacode.class), masterClassName));

      MethodSpec.Builder methodBuilder = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("setHello")
            .addAnnotation(Override.class)
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
            .returns(void.class)
            .addParameter(masterClassName, "master");

      for (Element element : roundContext.elements()) {
        String fieldName = element.getSimpleName().toString();
        methodBuilder.addStatement("master.$L = \"Hello, Jeta\"", fieldName);
      }

      builder.addMethod(methodBuilder.build());
      return false;
    }
}
```

#### Step 5: Metacode

All the required for code generating classes are created and we're ready to try. But first, we need to add `jeta.properties` file in order to configurate `Jeta`. You can find more details about this file [on this page](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide/config.html). The file should be located in the root package. For our tutorial its content would be:

```
metasitory.package=org.brooth.jeta.samples
processors.add=org.brooth.jeta.samples.apt.SayHelloProcessor
```

Next, modify `SayHelloApp`. Instead of initializing `text` field we'll put `Hello` annotation on it:

```
public class SayHelloApp {
     @Hello
     String text;
}
```

And `build.gradle`:

```
group 'org.brooth.jeta-samples'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

compileJava {
    options.sourcepath = files('src/main/java')
}

dependencies {
    apt project(':apt')
    compile project(':common')
    compile 'org.brooth.jeta:jeta:+'
}
```

Now we're ready to generate metacode. Run next command in your console:

```
./gradlew assemble
```

If there is no problems so far, we'll see `SayHelloApp_Metacode` file under `app/build` directory:

[image: SayHelloApp_Metacode]

#### Step 6: Controller

[Controllers](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide/at-runtime.html) are the classes that apply metacode to the [masters](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide/at-runtime.html). Let's create one  for `HelloMetacode` in `app` module:

```
 package org.brooth.jeta.samples;

 import org.brooth.jeta.MasterController;
 import org.brooth.jeta.metasitory.Metasitory;

 public class SayHelloController<M> extends MasterController<M, HelloMetacode<M>> {

     public SayHelloController(Metasitory metasitory, M master) {
       super(metasitory, master, Hello.class, false);
     }

     public void setHello() {
       for (HelloMetacode<M> metacode : metacodes)
         metacode.setHello(master);
     }
 }
```

#### Step 7: MetaHelper

`MetaHelper` is a simple static-helper class. You shouldn't use it in your project if you are not comfortable with static helpers. You can read more details about this class on [this page](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide/meta-helper.html).

Anyway, let's create `MetaHelper` in `app` module:

```
package org.brooth.jeta.samples;

import org.brooth.jeta.metasitory.MapMetasitory;
import org.brooth.jeta.metasitory.Metasitory;

public class MetaHelper {

    private static MetaHelper instance;
    private final Metasitory metasitory;

    public static MetaHelper getInstance() {
      if (instance == null)
        instance = new MetaHelper("org.brooth.jeta.samples");
      return instance;
    }

    private MetaHelper(String metaPackage) {
      metasitory = new MapMetasitory(metaPackage);
    }

    public static void setHello(Object master) {
      new SayHelloController<>(getInstance().metasitory, master).setHello();
    }
}
```

Note that we must pass to `MapMetasitory` the same package (`"org.brooth.jeta.samples"`) that we specified as `metasitory.package` in `jeta.properties`.

#### Step 8: Usage

The last step - we invoke our `MetaHelper`'s method. Here is the complete listing of `SayHelloApp`:

```
package org.brooth.jeta.samples;

public class SayHelloApp {

    @Hello
    String text;

    public SayHelloApp() {
      MetaHelper.setHello(this);
    }

    public void sayHello() {
      System.out.print(text);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new SayHelloApp().sayHello();
    }
}
```

Finally, we can run `SayHelloApp`. In the console we should see:

```
Hello, Jeta
```

#### Links

- This tutorial on [GitHub](https://github.com/brooth/jeta-samples/tree/master/hello-jeta)
- [Jeta Website](http://jeta.brooth.org)
- [Jeta on Android](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide/androjeta/overview.html)

*Happy code-generating! :)*